# How to access class member using "this" within method within a foreach loop.?

Tags: jquery

I have an interesting problem.   Following is my javascript code .  when i run line  ***this.data.splice(k,1);*** gives an error:**"Cannot call method 'splice' of undefined "**.   I understand the issue as within the each loop this.data is not recognized because "this" means each row of the array.   the question is how do i call this.data in this case.  I tried tried passing the object by ref but it;s not working. I appreciate your help.  thanks.

```
var Pastopts = {
    index: 0,
    data: [ "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven" ],
    addOpt: function() {
          var  i = 0;
        $.each(this.data, function(k, v) {
            i++;
            if (i < 6) {
                this.data.splice(k, 1);
            }
        });
     console.log(this.data);
    }
}

Pastopts.addOpt();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var Pastopts = {
    index: 0,
    data: [ "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven" ],
    addOpt: function() {
          var  i = 0;
          var t_d = this.data;
        $.each(this.data, function(k, v) {
            i++;
            if (i < 6) {
                t_d.splice(k, 1);
            }
        });
     console.log(this.data);
    }
}

Pastopts.addOpt();
```